# The Fastest Ninja in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Namikaze Minato and the Fourth Raikage are considered to be the fastest moving ninjas.

However, in a fight between the Raikage and Naruto, Naruto dodges the Raikage's full speed.

In terms of speed, did Naruto surpass Minato?

Comment: Naruto fought the 3rd raikage that was revived in the ninja war so he wasn't at full power anyways. Minato teleported using seals, so unless Naruto is teleporting ....then no he isn't faster.

Comment: Where does Shisui Uchiha come in on the list? He could create a half dozen or more "clones" just out of afterimages without any actual teleporting.

Comment: First of all, people need to define what speed is.. It is the time taken to move from one place to another. Doesn't matter whether it's by walking, running or teleporting. The person that consumes minimal time to do that will be the fastest. So my opinion would be Minato, Tobirama and Obito (including Sasuke and Shisui) are faster than Raikage and Naruto

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically, [Minato Namikaze](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato_Namikaze) is still titled as the fastest ninja. Take a look at the signature Ninjutsu of Minato, the [Flying Thunder God Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique). It's classified as one of the [Space-Time Ninjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Space%E2%80%93Time_Ninjutsu), which are techniques that allow the users to teleport to another location instantaneously. No one can exceed the speed with using only physical power.
If you're talking about the comparison of **raw** physical speed, [Fourth Raikage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/A_(Fourth_Raikage)) takes the lead. [Naruto Uzumaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto) is still pretty fast, but he only surpasses the Fourth Raikage when he's in [Nine-Tails Chakra Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode).

Comment: Is minato faster than tobirama senju?

Comment: @Joze Tobirama mark the seal with only using his hand. So when he want to teleport to further place, he need to first visit the destination and mark the seal, and now he can teleport to the destination whenever he want. While Minato, he most commonly applied the unique seal in advance to his special kunai, which he would scatter all over his desired destinations. This would make Minato teleport faster than Tobirama.

Comment: @HappyFace What makes you say that Tobirama cannot do the same as Minato and mark seals on kunai and scatter them at desired locations as Minato does? Tobirama is capable of doing the exact same thing. So since its the same technique, we might say that both Tobirama and Minato stand at same speeds

Answer (score 1):

No. Minato's speed is attributed to his Flying Thunder God technique (Hiraishin), which allows him to travel to any marked place on the planet nearly instantly.

Naruto is very fast for short distances, but purely by feats Minato still wins in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on whether you mean dead or alive. Alive, I believe the Raikage is the fastest ninja, because Naruto is very fast while dependent on the Nine-Tails' chakra. The Raikage built up that speed on his own.

If the dead counts, I believe it's Minato Namikaze. Although he did use his Flying Thunder God technique, he did have to train to build enough speed to even use the teleportation technique.

Answer (score 1):

Tsunade said Naruto is on par with the speed of the 4th Raikage in biyuu mode so either one. Minato teleports and Obito moves between dimensions so they dont count

Answer (score 0):

Naruto. He has already outrun the 4th Raikage.

People say Naruto is only as fast/strong due to the Kyuubi.

To be fair, I think 9 Tails Chakra Mode is a part of Naruto. Just because they can remove it or grant it doesn't mean it's not a part of him. Same as Uchiha, just because they can remove the Sharingan doesn't mean it isn't a part of their abilities. A lot of people exclude the Nine Tails Mode from the list of Abilities Naruto possess which is unfair. Although it's not a Natural ability that he inherited from birth, there are a lot of abilities from strong characters that came from outside sources (ie. Kakashi, Bee etc), or Jinchuriki's that didn't reach anywhere near the Skill and Chakra Control Naruto possesses.
I would understand the assumption that he's just some noob if you would take scenes from the early days (Orochimaru vs Naruto) who simply used the Chakra Leakage from the Kyuubi once in a while without really developing/controlling/mastering/enhancing it, but that's definitely not the case.

Source: Episode 282-283 Naruto Shippuden (Naruto vs Raikage).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest ninja is actually Might Guy.

Watch the fight with him and Madara and you'll see. Minato does have anything on him.